# select latest element from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a query to retrieve values from two columns using mysql table

My table has the following strucutre

```
| ID |  user_id   |        datetime     |        message     | 
| 1  |     21     | 2012-05-10 04:13:01 |        message1    |  
| 2  |     07     | 2012-05-10 04:17:51 |        message2    |  
| 3  |     21     | 2012-05-11 04:21:51 |        message3    | 
| 4  |     21     | 2012-05-11 04:43:51 |        message4    | 
| 5  |     07     | 2012-05-11 04:21:51 |        message5    | 
| 5  |     21     | 2012-05-11 04:43:51 |        message6    |
```

i wrote the below query

$query="SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM `messages` where user_id=21 and date=2012-05-11";

but i am not getting latest record from table iam getting null value

help us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM messages where user_id=21 and date LIKE '2012-05-11%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DATE(date)` to get date of timestamp. MySQL function `DATE()` extracts only date without hours, minutes and seconds.

Here is your query:

```
SELECT MAX(datetime) 
FROM messages
WHERE user_id = 21 AND DATE(date) = '2012-05-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
$query="SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM messages where user_id=21";
```

**Update:** 
In your question, you didn't specify if you wanted to retrieve last record for a certain date. If you do, you'd need to use MySQL's [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

Answer (score 0):

Your query asks for ".....date=2012-05-11";"  but your table does not have the field named date? did you mean datetime? if so, you may want to try ".....datetime like '2012-05-11%'";

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the most recent record? You can get this with a subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM messages)";
```